# Concurrency of the heights of a tetrahedron with opposite edges perpendicular.

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, orthogonality

Can anyone give me a vectorial solution to the following problem:

> Prove that if each pair of opposite edges of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ is perpendicular (that is, $AB \perp CD$ and $AC \perp BD$ and $AD \perp BC$), then the heights of the tetrahedron are concurrent.

Here, the *heights* (also known as the *altitudes*) of tetrahedron $ABCD$ are the perpendicular from $A$ to the plane $BCD$, and three other similarly defined perpendiculars.

Tetrahedra satisfying the condition of this problem are called [orthocentric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron), and this appears to be a known result.

Comment: You are with an orthocentric tetrahedron.
See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron)

Comment: A very deep document : (http://www.geometrie.tuwien.ac.at/havlicek/pub/hoehen.pdf) entering in higher mathematics... On the same vein (https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu/Monge-final.pdf)

Comment: Does it have to be vectorial? Because you can do it by arguing about perpendicular lines forming perpendicular planes and deducing the result from rigorous purely geometric arguments. And you do not have to use any calculations -- vecotrial or otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it should be vectorial. As an application of scalar product

Answer (score 4):

That is a simple exercise in visualization. Imagine that $A,B,C$ are embedded in the $xy$ plane (the screen) and $D$ lies on the $z$-axis (orthogonal to the screen), so that the origin $O$ is the projection of $D$ on the plane through $A,B,C$. Since $DB\perp AC$ (in $3$D) we have $OB\perp AC$ (in $2$D). Similarly we get $OA\perp BC$ and $OC\perp AB$, hence $O$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$.

[image]

The orthocenter $H_A$ of the $BCD$ face lies on on the line joining $D$ with its projection on $BC$, hence the projection of $H_A$ on the $ABC$ plane lies on the $AO$ line. In particular the lines $AH_A,BH_B,CH_C,DH_D$ are concurrent when projected on the $ABC$ plane. The same holds by replacing $ABC$ with any face of the tetrahedron, hence the lines $AH_A,BH_B,CH_C,DH_D$ are concurrent in the $3$D space.

Comment: This is very nice visualisation idea, but what about a vectorial solution? Maybe using scalar product?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using vectors (since I don't trust pictures too much):

We let $\left\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right\rangle $ denote the scalar
product of two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are
three non-collinear points in space, then $XYZ$ shall denote the plane through $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

We first notice the following simple fact:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a plane, and let $x$ and $y$ be two
>   non-parallel lines on $\mathcal{P}$. Let $v$ be a line such that $v\perp x$
>   and $v\perp y$. Then, $v\perp\mathcal{P}$.

This is just saying that a line $v$ is orthogonal to a plane $\mathcal{P}$ if
it is orthogonal to some two non-parallel lines on $\mathcal{P}$. If you
define your stereometry synthetically by some axioms (not that I know what
these axioms would be), then Lemma 1 is probably one of the fundamental
results or even one of the axioms. If you define your stereometry as the study
of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then it easily follows from the bilinearity of
the scalar product (indeed, if we pick nonzero vectors $\mathbf{v}$,
$\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ running along the lines $v$, $x$ and $y$,
respectively, then $v\perp x$ and $v\perp y$ lead to $\left\langle
\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}\right\rangle =0$ and $\left\langle \mathbf{v}
,\mathbf{y}\right\rangle =0$, which entails that $\left\langle \mathbf{v}
,\lambda\mathbf{x}+\mu\mathbf{y}\right\rangle =0$ for all $\lambda,\mu
\in\mathbb{R}$; but this yields that $v$ is orthogonal to any line on
$\mathcal{P}$).

Now, let $H$ be a common point of

- the plane through $B$ orthogonal to the line $AC$;
- the plane through $C$ orthogonal to the line $AD$;
- the plane through $D$ orthogonal to the line $AB$.

(Such an $H$ exists, since the lines $AB$, $AC$ and $AD$ are pairwise non-parallel.)

The point $H$ lies on the plane through $B$ orthogonal to the line $AC$ (by
its definition). Thus, $HB\perp AC$. Similarly, $HC\perp AD$ and $HD\perp BC$.

We have $\overrightarrow{HD}=\overrightarrow{HB}+\overrightarrow{BD}$, and
thus
\begin{align*}
\left\langle \overrightarrow{HD},\overrightarrow{AC}\right\rangle  &
=\left\langle \overrightarrow{HB}+\overrightarrow{BD},\overrightarrow{AC}
\right\rangle =\underbrace{\left\langle \overrightarrow{HB}
,\overrightarrow{AC}\right\rangle }_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since }HB\perp
AC\text{)}}}+\underbrace{\left\langle \overrightarrow{BD},\overrightarrow{AC}
\right\rangle }_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since }BD\perp AC\text{)}}}\\
& =0+0=0.
\end{align*}
In other words, $HD\perp AC$. Now, the lines $BC$ and $AC$ are two
non-parallel lines on the plane $ABC$. Hence, from $HD\perp BC$ and $HD\perp
AC$, we obtain $HD\perp ABC$ (by Lemma 1, applied to $\mathcal{P}=ABC$,
$v=HD$, $x=BC$ and $y=AC$). Thus, $H$ belongs to the height of the tetrahedron
$ABCD$ from the vertex $D$.

We have shown that $HD\perp ABC$. The same argument (but with $C$, $D$ and $B$
playing the roles of the points $B$, $C$ and $D$) yields $HB\perp ACD$
(because our definition of $H$ does not change if we cyclically rotate the
variables $B$, $C$ and $D$). Thus, $H$ belongs to the height of the
tetrahedron $ABCD$ from the vertex $B$.

We have shown that $HB\perp ACD$. The same argument (but with $C$, $D$ and $B$
playing the roles of the points $B$, $C$ and $D$) yields $HC\perp ADB$
(because our definition of $H$ does not change if we cyclically rotate the
variables $B$, $C$ and $D$). Thus, $H$ belongs to the height of the
tetrahedron $ABCD$ from the vertex $C$.

We have $HD\perp ABC$ and thus $HD\perp BC$ (since the line $BC$ lies on the
plane $ABC$). Now, $\overrightarrow{HA}=\overrightarrow{HD}
-\overrightarrow{AD}$, so that
\begin{align*}
\left\langle \overrightarrow{HA},\overrightarrow{BC}\right\rangle  &
=\left\langle \overrightarrow{HD}-\overrightarrow{AD},\overrightarrow{BC}
\right\rangle =\underbrace{\left\langle \overrightarrow{HD}
,\overrightarrow{BC}\right\rangle }_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since }HD\perp
BC\text{)}}}-\underbrace{\left\langle \overrightarrow{AD},\overrightarrow{BC}
\right\rangle }_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since }AD\perp BC\text{)}}}\\
& =0-0=0.
\end{align*}
In other words, $HA\perp BC$. The same argument (but with $C$, $D$ and $B$
playing the roles of the points $B$, $C$ and $D$) yields $HA\perp CD$ (because
our definition of $H$ does not change if we cyclically rotate the variables
$B$, $C$ and $D$). Now, the lines $BC$ and $CD$ are two non-parallel lines on
the plane $BCD$. Hence, from $HA\perp BC$ and $HA\perp CD$, we obtain $HA\perp
BCD$ (by Lemma 1, applied to $\mathcal{P}=BCD$, $v=HA$, $x=BC$ and $y=CD$).
Thus, $H$ belongs to the height of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ from the vertex $A$.

We have now proven that the point $H$ belongs to all four heights of the
tetrahedron $ABCD$. Hence, these four heights are concurrent. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{DA}=\vec{a},$ $\vec{DB}=\vec{b}$ and $\vec{DC}=\vec{c}.$

Thus, $$AB^2+CD^2=AC^2+BD^2$$ it's
$$(\vec{b}-\vec{a})^2+\vec{c}^2=(\vec{c}-\vec{a})^2+\vec{b}^2$$ or
$$\vec{a}\vec{b}=\vec{a}\vec{c}$$ or
$$\vec{a}(\vec{b}-\vec{c})=0$$ or $$AD\perp BC.$$
Similarly, we obtain that $BD\perp AC$ and $CD\perp AB.$

Now, let $DK$ be an altitude of the tetrahedron and $AK\cap BC=\{E\}.$

Also, let $AF$ be an altitude of $\Delta ADE$.

We see that $BC\perp AE$ and $BC\perp DK$.

Thus, $BC\perp(ADE)$ and since $AF\subset(ADC),$ we obtain $BC\perp AF$.

Id est, $AF\perp BC$ and $AF\perp DF,$ which says $AF\perp(DBC)$ and we got that $AF$ is an altitude of the  tetrahedron.

But $AF\subset(ADE)$ and $DK\subset(ADE),$ which says that $AF$ and $DK$ intersect.

Can you end it now?